# API demo : what's this box called?

Tags: android

[image: ScreenShot]

What is that little box at the bottom showing `"d"` called? How do I enable it in my filtered `SearchView`? Where else can it be used?

Could it be some kind of a `Toast`? I looked and looked in API sources and couldn't find how to define it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a PopupWindow http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html. You do not need to enable it. Its used by default when you set your ListView to

```
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and the PopupWindow shows up when you set or clear the filter text

```
listView.setFilterText("d");
```

Comment: I looked in the code and never saw popup window mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I edited my post to explain. Its implemented by default by ListView respectively AbsListView

Answer (score 1):

i found out how to get rid of that ugly popup window. The trick is to work with filter directly.The code below assumes you have implemented filterable in your customAdapter.

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        m_listView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        ContactsAdapter ca = (ContactsAdapter)lv.getAdapter();
        ca.getFilter().filter(newText);
        //following line was causing the ugly popup window.
        //m_listView.setFilterText(newText);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know it just repeats what you have typed in as a search key.  If you have a list without a text box to type your search key, its quite handy to know what you have typed. 
Cliff